# How to license client-side apps

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to find out how I can distribute an app with licenses for a group, preferably using Azure.

The flow I'm envisioning is an installer for the application only allows X number of users and has to verify this with a server somewhere, ie if a group has bought 100 copies of the software they are restricted to using only 100 installs.

Will Azure AD do this, or is this something that I would need to develop myself?

Answer (score 0):

•   You can surely distribute an app and monitor the licenses for that application that is deployed for a group of users by ensuring that you have **Microsoft 365 license** with you. **With Microsoft 365, the management of licenses for an ISV app, i.e., Independent Software Vendor app (software vendor other than Microsoft) can be easily done by adding that application as a custom application in the Microsoft 365 admin centre through the ‘Integrated Apps’ option** as shown below: -

[image: Integrated apps in M365]

•   Similarly, after adding an app to the Microsoft 365 admin centre as shown above, you can **assign licenses to the added application as below by going to the ‘Licenses’ section in ‘Billing’ part of the M365 portal**. Also, *`while assigning licenses, you can select a group of users, select multiple users, or only select a single user for assigning the software license for the added app from ISV`*.

In this way, through Microsoft 365, you can surely manage the distribution of licenses for an app for which the installation on a specific number of users and their devices needs to be managed through it.

[image: M365 App addition]

For more detailed information regarding the addition of apps for an ISV in the Microsoft 365 portal, kindly refer to the below link: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/test-and-deploy-microsoft-365-apps?source=recommendations&view=o365-worldwide***